# How to create a countdown timer before a function is performed

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

What I want to do is have a coin flip which will start a countdown when the flip button is pressed or if instructed to elsewhere. Then I want it to countdown 3, 2, 1 and display that on the screen. When the countdown is complete it will display heads or tails. The reason for this is so I do not have to create an animation of the coin flipping instead a delay to build the tension.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Coin Toss </title>
        <script>
            function toss() {
            if (Math.random()>.5) {
            window.document.coin.src = "CT.jpg";
            }
            else {
            window.document.coin.src = "T.jpg";
            }
            return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img name="coin" src="questionmark.png">
        <form action="" onSubmit="return toss();">
            <input type="submit" value="TOSS">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval` and/or `setTimeout` is what you're looking for

Comment: http://i713.photobucket.com/albums/ww138/irene1212/quarter-2-textures1.gif

Comment: Make sure to handle the situation where user keeps clicking the button while timer is still running.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a `setInterval`, here is an example:

Javascript:

```
var current = 3;
var elem = document.getElementById('toss');
var intervalId = setInterval( function(){
    if( current > 0 ){
        elem.innerHTML = "<h1>" + current + "</h1>";
    } else {
        if( Math.random() > .5 ){
            elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.thecoinspot.com/25c/1932%20Type%201%20Silver%20Washington%20Quarter%20Obv.png">';
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.thecoinspot.com/25c/1988%20Type%202%20Clad%20Washington%20Quarter%20Reverse.png">';
        }
        clearInterval( intervalId );
    }
    current--;
}, 1000 ); // 1000 ms = 1s
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toss"><div>
```

Also here is a Fiddle so you can test it out and see what it does:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cedriking/cLs9r3m6/

**For your second question** (in the comment), do this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>This is my title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="toss"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var current = 3;
        var elem = document.getElementById('toss');
        var intervalId = setInterval( function(){
            if( current > 0 ){
                elem.innerHTML = "<h1>" + current + "</h1>";
            } else {
                if( Math.random() > .5 ){
                    elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.thecoinspot.com/25c/1932%20Type%201%20Silver%20Washington%20Quarter%20Obv.png">';
                } else {
                    elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.thecoinspot.com/25c/1988%20Type%202%20Clad%20Washington%20Quarter%20Reverse.png">';
                }
                clearInterval( intervalId );
            }
            current--;
        }, 1000 ); // 1000 ms = 1s

        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the info but would you be able to help me on where i should implement this code into my current code as ive tried a few things but couldnt get it to work?

Comment: This is what ive changed from your code, but i cannot get it to run in my browser, what shall i add?:

Comment: var current = 3;
var elem = document.getElementById('toss');
var intervalId = setInterval( function(){
if( current > 0 ){
elem.innerHTML = "
<h1>" + current + "</h1>
";
} else {
if( Math.random() > .5 ){
elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://csgowild.com/assets/counter-terrorist.png">';
} else {
elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://csgowild.com/assets/terrorist.png">';
}
clearInterval( intervalId );
}
current--;
}, 1000 ); // 1000 ms = 1s

Comment: you have double `;` in your code right before `} else`, maybe it's because of that, also does your div has the id toss?

Comment: the code works in jsfiddle i just need to know how to run it in a browser like putting it into a text document then doing .html

Comment: I added a sample of how it could go in an html file, and to create this file you can simply use Notepad and in save do all files and put the name file.html you just have to change the image with yours.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `setTimeout`. In this instance I've removed the form as you don't strictly need it imo, and used event listeners so that the JS call is removed from the HTML.

HTML

```
<img id="coin"/><br/>
<button id="toss">Toss</button><br/>
<div id="count"></div>
```

JS

```
function toss() {
    var div = document.getElementById('coin');
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
        coin.src = "CT.jpg";
    } else {
        coin.src = "T.jpg";
    }
}

function countDown() {
    var count = 3, timer;
    var div = document.getElementById('count');

    // if count is not 0, add the new count to the
    // count element and loop again, reducing the count number
    // otherwise erase the count element, clear the timeout
    // and run the toss function
    var loop = function loop (count) {
       if (count > 0) {
           div.textContent = count--;
           timer = setTimeout(loop, 1000, count);
       } else {
           div.textContent = '';
           clearTimeout(timer);
           toss();
       }
    }

    // start the countdown
    loop(count);
}

var button = document.getElementById('toss');
button.addEventListener('click', countDown, false);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x1toocem/5/)